# PHP comparing two datavalues

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to compare two strings, one with the username that the user is entering, and the 2nd one is the data that my program pulls from the database. Here is my php code:

```
$sqlCheck = "SELECT Username FROM location WHERE Username ='$usernamebeingreq'" ; 
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sqlCheck);
$result2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
$resultCheck = false;
//mysqli_query($con, $sqlCheck);
if((strcmp($result2, $usernamebeingreq) == 1))
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO pending_req (fromUser, toUser) VALUES ('$username', '$usernamebeingreq')";
    $resultCheck = true;
}
```

$usernamebeingreq is equal to the user that they enter in, and the result should be equal to that when it pulls it from the database. I'm not sure why it's not working correctly.

Comment: you need to add a reference in $result2 to the column that you are checking against. what does var_dump($result2) give you ?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: 1. You're overwriting `$result2`, 2. `strcmp` is for comparing strings, not objects or other primitives. 3. `strcmp === 0` when strings are equal, not `1`. 4. Your SQL is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I get NULL @Maximus2012

Comment: Also, you cannot mix and match mysqli_ and mysql_ functions in your code like that.

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the response! How can I make things less vulnerable?

Comment: Please show the SQL you are executing in `$sqlCheck` I am sure there is at least one better way of doing this.

Comment: @RiggsFolly$sqlCheck = "SELECT Username FROM location WHERE Username ='$usernamebeingreq'" ;

Comment: Yea I might have known. If you are using the variable as a parameter in the SELECT, then why test it after you get it off the database. Just test that you got something returned. Or better still do a `select count(*) where ....`

Comment: so just check if thats null or not? @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot combine mysql_ and mysqli_ like this. 
   Also, you need to iterate through the result set to get the value and compare it then:

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sqlCheck);
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
    $username_to_check = $row2['Username'];
}
$resultCheck = false;

if((strcmp($username_to_check , $usernamebeingreq) == 1))
/*  rest of your code */
```

More about mysqli_fetch_ functions: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Also, like RiggsFolly mentioned in the comments above, this all may not even be needed since the required check can be implemented in the actual query itself rather than comparing strings like this.